# SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed even when it works with testsaslauthd

Tags: postfix, saslauthd

I'm having some trouble configuring client authentication using saslauthd and postfix on ubuntu 22.04. The issue is that users are not getting authenticated although the user exists. It's my first time setting up postfix and saslauthd so it might be obvious to some of you serverfault sharks.

The email sending works fine using mail command. Using telnet everything looks okay but with remote SMTP client with auth it doesn't work. I'm 6 hours deep and close to quitting (for today).

Doing a telnet from a remote server:

```
telnet mail.mydomain.com 25
Trying IP...
Connected to mail.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
EHLO mydomain.com
250-mail.mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH SCRAM-SHA-1 SCRAM-SHA-256 DIGEST-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
421 4.4.2 mail.mydomain.com Error: timeout exceeded
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Verifying that the user i created actually exists

```
testsaslauthd -u lukas -p mypassword -r mydomain.com
0: OK "Success."
```

/var/log/mail.log (please notice that verification FAILS here even though it has just been successfully tested above.

```
Mar  9 04:36:42 postfix/smtpd[42026]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Mar  9 04:36:42 postfix/smtpd[42026]: warning: IPbredband.3.dk[IP]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Mar  9 04:36:42 postfix/smtpd[42026]: lost connection after AUTH from IP.bredband.3.dk[IP]
Mar  9 04:36:42 postfix/smtpd[42026]: disconnect from IP.bredband.3.dk[IP] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 commands=3/4
```

Where I’m currently trying to login via nodemailer’s SMTP module (this shouldn't be the issue - but better safe than sorry):

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.mydomain.com",
  port: 25,
  secure: false, // Use `true` for port 465, `false` for all other ports
  auth: {
    user: "lukas@mydomain.com”,
    pass: “myapassword
  },
});

 
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

  const info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Maddison Foo Koch " <username@mydomain>', // sender address
    to: "admin@somereceiver.com”, // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello!", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  return res.status(200).json({ data:"ok", info: JSON.stringify(info) });
  });
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf (chroot enabled)

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf (highly believe something is wrong in this file)

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no 
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


# auth
#smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sasl_path = var/run/saslauthd/mux
#smtpd_sasl_path = var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd/mux
#smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mydomain.com, localhost.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

/etc/default/saslauthd

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/run/saslauthd"
```

Furthermore, there is a symlink between /var/run/saslauthd and /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd

Any hints or help is much appreciated!

Comment: could it be /etc/sasldb2 need a symlink too into /var/spool/postfix/etc when it chrooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add modify the following file /etc/default/saslauthd

```
    START=yes 
    
      
    DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon" 
    
    NAME="saslauthd" 
    
    MECHANISMS="sasldb"
    MECH_OPTIONS="" 
    
     
     
    
    THREADS=5 
    # modified to look in the chrooted folder which has a symlink to var/run/saslauthd and can be run by postfix
    OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Comment: welcome wsb memes, remember to accept your answer, else we will be reminded to solve this problem until the end of the universum to do so.